# Ubuntu 20 GDM (login screen) freezes after disconnecting from cisco anyconnect VPN

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I use cisco anyconnect on my work laptop (Ubuntu 20) to connect to the network at work.

1. If I lock my screen **before** connecting to the VPN, I can unlock it and login without issue.
2. If I am connected to the VPN and I lock my screen, I can unlock it, but it authenticates with the servers at the office, so it takes a long time to login.
3. However, if I connect to the VPN then disconnect from it and lock my screen, when I try to login it freezes and stays frozen indefinitely.

I have tried using a TTY session to kill the VPN and restart GDM (which works but obviously kills all my windows and I can't open cisco anyconnect when I am logged in). I have also looked at the system logs and I can't see anything unusual.

Any advice appreciated! Let me know if you would like me to post the output of anything.

Thanks in advanced, Sam

Comment: Same here, but also cannot unlock while VPN is active.